# Навигация во Flutter

Tags: route, flutter, dart, navigation

Учусь работать с flutter и решил разобраться с роутами (routes). Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

У меня есть несколько экранов: **Экран_1**, **Экран_2**, **Экран_3**.
С **Экрана_1** я перехожу на **Экран_2**, от туда на **Экран_3**, от туда обратно на **Экран_1**. Теперь при нажатии клавиши *"Назад"* у меня с **Экрана_1** возвращается на **Экран_3**, потом на **Экран_2** и т.д. Вопрос, как сделать так что бы если я вернулся с **Экрана_3** на **Экран_1**, то при нажатии на клавишу *"Назад"* не мог бы вернуться обратно на **Экран_3**? И как убрать отображение этой стрелки *"назад"*, находящийся вверху экрана?

Пример:
[**Video**](http://recordit.co/mIlhkbr4kO)

**Gif:**

[image: GIF]

Код роутов:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quest/Screens/Endings/endings.dart';
import 'package:quest/Screens/NewGame/levelChoice.dart';
import 'package:quest/Screens/NewGame/newGame.dart';
import 'package:quest/Screens/Settings/settings.dart';
import 'package:quest/main.dart';

final routes = {
  '/': (BuildContext context) => new MyApp(),
  '/Endings': (BuildContext context) => new EndingsScreen(),
  '/LevelChoice': (BuildContext context) => new LevelChoiceScreen(),
  '/NewGame': (BuildContext context) => new NewGameScreen(),
  '/Settings': (BuildContext context) => new SettingsScreen()
};
```

Код main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quest/Config/Routes.dart';
import 'package:quest/Config/UiData.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: UiData.AppName,
    debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    initialRoute: '/',
    routes: routes,
  ));
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    UiData.deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(UiData.AppName + " " + UiData.AppVersion),
      ),

      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[

            Container(
              height: UiData.deviceSize.height / 5,
              width: UiData.deviceSize.width,

              child: Center(
                child: Text(UiData.AppName,
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 100.0,
                    fontFamily: 'MainFonts',
                    color: Colors.black,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ),

            Container(
              height: UiData.deviceSize.height / 10,
              width: UiData.deviceSize.width / 2,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),

              child: MaterialButton(
                height: UiData.deviceSize.height / 10,
                minWidth: UiData.deviceSize.width / 2,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                child: new Text(
                  "Новая игра",
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25.0,
                    fontFamily: 'ButtonFonts',
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/LevelChoice');
                },
                splashColor: Colors.redAccent,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Код выбора уровня:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quest/Config/UiData.dart';

class LevelChoiceScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Выбор уровня"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[

            Container(
              height: UiData.deviceSize.height / 10,
              width: UiData.deviceSize.width / 2,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),

              child: MaterialButton(
                height: UiData.deviceSize.height / 10,
                minWidth: UiData.deviceSize.width / 2,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                textColor: Colors.white,
                child: new Text(
                  "Акт 1",
                  style: new TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25.0,
                    fontFamily: 'ButtonFonts',
                    color: Colors.yellow,
                  ),
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/NewGame');
                },
                splashColor: Colors.redAccent,
              ),
            ),

            RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              },
              child: Text('Go back!'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Код новой игры:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewGameScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Новая игра"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/');
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел [***ответ тут***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50037710/flutter-move-to-a-new-screen-without-back)

При выборе уровня я должен использовать следующую навигацию:

```
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/route')
```

Вот как это выглядит в коде:

```
Container(
  height: UiData.deviceSize.height / 10,
  width: UiData.deviceSize.width / 2,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),

  child: MaterialButton(
    height: UiData.deviceSize.height / 10,
    minWidth: UiData.deviceSize.width / 2,
    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    textColor: Colors.white,
    child: new Text(
      "Акт 1",
      style: new TextStyle(
        fontSize: 25.0,
        fontFamily: 'ButtonFonts',
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
    ),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, '/NewGame');
    },
    splashColor: Colors.redAccent,
  ),
),
```

Тогда код возвращения на главный экран из экрана игры выглядит следующим образом:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class NewGameScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Новая игра"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```